# Stored Procedures VB.NET MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, dbnull

Hello I still having problems, it brings me DBnull and I tried the Store procedure and works. This is my code. If someone could help me I will appreciate.

```
        conexion.Open()
        command.Connection = conexion
        command.CommandText = "TraerPaisOrigen"
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cod_Dua", TxtCodDUA.Text)
        command.Parameters("@Cod_Dua").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input



        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PaisOrigen", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
        command.Parameters("@_PaisOrigen").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'XML_PaisOrigen is a String

        XML_PaisOrigen = command.Parameters(0).Value.ToString




        conexion.Close()
```

My Store Procedured

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TraerPaisOrigen( IN Cod_Dua INT, OUT _PaisOrigen VARCHAR(2))
```

Comment: what works and what don;t? I can't find any question mention above?!

Comment: The result, doesn't bring me the OUT Variable to my result parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cod_Dua", TxtCodDUA.Text)
command.Parameters("@Cod_Dua").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
```

should be this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cod_Dua", CInt(TxtCodDUA.Text))
```

This:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PaisOrigen", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
command.Parameters("@_PaisOrigen").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
```

should be this:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@_PaisOrigen", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
```

This:

```
XML_PaisOrigen = command.Parameters(0).Value.ToString
```

should be this:

```
XML_PaisOrigen = command.Parameters(1).Value.ToString()
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response, but still brings me empty the output parameter. I tried several ways. I cant find the answer of my problem. This is how I call my STORED PROCEDURE and works fine in DB. SET @Cod_Dua=1;
CALL TraerPaisOrigen(@Cod_Dua,@_PaisOrigen);
SELECT @_PaisOrigen;   ANSWER AT RESULT: @_PaisOrigen: XX

Comment: Code in comments is all but unreadable unless it's a single line.  Please update your question with your current VB and SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

```
         Try
            conexion.Open()
            command.Connection = conexion
            command.CommandText = "TraerPaisOrigen"
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cod_Dua", CInt(TxtCodDUA.Text))
            command.Parameters("@Cod_Dua").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input              
            command.Parameters.Add("@_PaisOrigen", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

            XML_PaisOrigen = command.Parameters(1).Value.ToString

           conexion.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & vbCrLf & "Error al ejecutar << " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Test")

        End Try
```

This how I call the SP in DB in Mysql and works perfect.

```
SET @Cod_Dua=1;
CALL TraerPaisOrigen(@Cod_Dua,@_PaisOrigen);
SELECT @_PaisOrigen;
```

I am really losing my mind, I have look tutorials and video tutorials and all they do the same or similar. What else could be that SP is not sending me an answer from DB?
I have test this and doesn't bring nothing. Always goes to the else.

```
    If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
            XML_PaisOrigen = command.Parameters(1).Value.ToString
        Else
            MsgBox("Nothing!")
        End If
```